# SimpleCursorAdapter not reloading data&view on insert in ContentProvider

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, simplecursoradapter

this code is working fine - i'm loading a bunch of rows into the SimpleCursorAdapter and the ListView displays them. nice.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
Cursor cursor;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.main_lv_projects);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    String[] columns = new String[] { CompassDataProvider.ORG_NAME };
    int[] names = new int[] { R.id.organisation_row_name};

    cursor = this.managedQuery(CompassDataProvider.CONTENT_URI_ORGANISATIONS, null, null, null, null);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.organisation_row, cursor, columns, names);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    startManagingCursor(cursor);
}
```

But when i'm inserting a new row via

```
long rowID = db.getWritableDatabase().insert(CompassDBHelper.ORGS_TABLE_NAME, "", values);
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI_ORGANISATIONS, null);
return Uri.withAppendedPath(CONTENT_URI_ORGANISATIONS, ""+rowID);
```

the list view is not updateing itself - i thought the SimpleCursorAdapter is notified an can then reload its view - not?

the new row is created - i checked on this

when i'm using

```
cursor.requery();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

in my UI threat the new data gets loaded correctly...  whats the observer/listener pattern here that i did not get? :)

thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

The cursor is being passed into the SimpleCursorAdapter by value and not reference.  So, calling cursor.requery has no effect.   To get this to work the way you want, you're really going to need to implement a listAdapter and process your cursor in there.

Comment: ListAdapter or CursorAdapter? the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange) say "By default, CursorAdapter objects will get this notification."